# flask-login:Exception: No user_loader has been installed for this LoginManager. Add one with the 'LoginManager.user_loader' decorator

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I want to use flask_login to manager user login but some error like this:

Exception: No user_loader has been installed for this LoginManager. Add one with the 'LoginManager.user_loader' decorator.

this is my models.py (PS:I use Flask peewee to build my models)

```
from peewee import *
from playhouse.fields import ManyToManyField
from .__init__ import login_manager
from flask_login import UserMixin, AnonymousUserMixin

db = SqliteDatabase('adminSystem.db')

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class User(UserMixin, BaseModel):
    name = CharField()
    email = CharField()
    is_admin = BooleanField()
    username = CharField()
    passwd_hash = CharField()
    teacher = ForeignKeyField('self', related_name='students', null=True)

    #def is_authenticated(self):
    #    return True

    #def is_active(self):
    #    return True

    #def is_anonymous(self):
    #    return False

    #def get_id(self):
    #    try:
    #        return unicode(self.id)
    #   except NameError:
    #        return str(self.id)

class Homework(BaseModel):
    owner = ForeignKeyField(User, related_name='homeworks', null=True)
    pub_datetime = DateTimeField()
    connect = TextField()
    homework_id =CharField()
    file_url = CharField()

class Score(BaseModel):
    homework_id = CharField()
    stu_id = CharField()
    grade = IntegerField()
    file_url = CharField()

class AnonymousUser(AnonymousUserMixin):
    def can(self, permissions):
        return False

    def is_administrator(self):
        return False

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(userid):
    try:
        #: Flask Peewee used here to return the user object
        return User.get(User.id==userid)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

and this is some part of my view.py

```
from flask import render_template, url_for, redirect, request, g
from . import auth
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from ..models import db, User, Homework, Score
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, login_required, current_user

@auth.before_app_request
def before_request():
    g.user = current_user

@auth.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['role'] == 'teacher':
            user = User.get(User.username == request.form['username'])
            if check_password_hash(user.passwd_hash, request.form['password']):
                login_user(user)
                return redirect(url_for('main.post'))
            return render_template('login.html')
        elif request.form['role'] == 'student':
            user = User.get(User.username == request.form['username'])
            if check_password_hash(user.passwd_hash, request.form['password']):
                login_user(user)
                return redirect(url_for('main.show'))
            return render_template('login.html')
    return render_template('login.html')
```

and there is a picture that I had try

[image]

Comment: when I put @login_manager.user_loader under login_manager.init_app(app) it works

Answer (score 9):

you can place this method

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return None
```

at after `login_manager.init_app(app)`

Comment: It works, but I don't understand why it works. It is strange, because in an other project, I don't need this and the project has the same structure. So I guess this is because I have updated the library.

Answer (score 4):

According to https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#configuring-your-application

> Once the actual application object has been created, you can configure
>   it for login with:
>
> login_manager.init_app(app)

After that, you can register callbacks by using decorators etc. So that the `login_manager` has the context to process.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (following Miguel Grinberg's tutorial, [part 6](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-vi-profile-page-and-avatars)), what was needed was just to restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

As @code said, but instead you return None try to return the user data.

Add in yourapp.py this code below the login_manager instance.

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.filter_by(user_id=id).first()
```

After that you can delete the `@login_manager` decorator and its respect function from your `model.py`

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem

```
@login_manager.user_loader
```

def load_user(username):
return get_user(username)

Comment: Before answering an old question having other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. It's unclear to me what the added value is when comparing it with these two already existing answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57980401/5698098 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/49849243/5698098? Also, take care to properly format your code, and provide an explanation rather than just only code as it doesn't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer and clarify any important differences which makes having this answer worthwhile.